# Large Size File Not Uploading in Yii 2.0 Framework

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

Large size pdf file not uploading in Yii2 Framework.

While Uploading am getting below error

**ERROR : fopen(importclaimattachment/Testing Results - Phase II.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

if the file size is below 2MB is uploading, more than 2MB is not uploading

**Controller Code:**

```
$model->attachment_to_be_stored = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'attachment_to_be_stored');
foreach ($model->attachment_to_be_stored as $file) 
                            {
                                $file->saveAs('importclaimattachment/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension);
                                $filename = 'importclaimattachment/' .$file->baseName. '.' . $file->extension;
                                $value->attach($filename);
                            }
```

**Model Code:**

```
['attachment_to_be_stored', 'file', 'extensions' => ['pdf', 'docx'], 
            'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 5, 'maxFiles'=>1000],
```

**Form Code:**

```
<?php
          echo $form->field($model, 'attachment_to_be_stored[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
              'options' => ['multiple' => true],
              'pluginOptions' => [
                'previewFileType' => 'any',
                'allowedFileExtensions' => ['pdf','docx'],
                'maxFileSize' => 5120,
              ]
          ]);
    ?>
```

Am stuck with this..Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: add this line off code at the very top of your script -> ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: Still getting same error @RafaelShkembi

Comment: hmm. Ok check this [article](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads) and be sure to check the upload_max_filesize,post_max_size on php.ini

Comment: Might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: @RafaelShkembi You should never set memory_limit to -1, unless you very know what you are doing. Memory limit is not the cause of this issue.

Comment: yeah already i have increased the size of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini file @RafaelShkembi

Comment: have you restart the services?

Comment: I hosted my files in godaddy server @RafaelShkembi

Comment: To take the configuration the services must restart